# Wordpress: Highlight active menu color on scroll and on click

Tags: wordpress

i am working on this Wordpress [website](http://ergon.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/home/)  and as you can see is a one scroll landing page. Every section as an `id` and this class `id` is connected to the navigation points like this

Example:

`http://ergon.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/home/#idee`

What i need is to highlight the active navigation point when you scroll with the mouse on the sections and when you click on the navigation on the relative link.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website has already been built with functionality that changes the class of the menu item once it's content/counterpart is in the viewport of the end user.

If you inspect the element, you will notice that the `a` tags in your menu receive a class `.mPS2id-highlight` when their content counterparts are in view.

Thusly, you can simply add a CSS rule to achieve your goal.

I've tested the rule below in firebug on your website and it seems to work fine (the `!important` was necessary):

```
.mPS2id-highlight {
  color: #b51339 !important;
}
```

If you would like to keep your border functionality, you can use the following rules instead:

```
.cssmenu > ul.menu > li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0 solid;
}
.mPS2id-highlight {
  border-color: #b51339 !important;
  color: #b51339 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need declare the highlight with javascript particularly you do with jquery in custom code de your wordpress with something like this:

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
});
```

also you look at the console of the browser  because it have an error in your page